# Linux Redhat "Screen" won't detach

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I've got a screen set up, I access it like this 'screen -r' it works fine, but when I go to put it in the background, I've previously used 'Ctrl a+d' but every time I try that now it puts '^A' in terminal instead and it won't detach :(

I've tried using Coda 2 rather than terminal but I'm still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

`^A` Is the default escape character for screen. If you have this problem, this means that the screen you are using has been configured to use a different escape character. Search for `escape` in the configuration file (`/etc/screenrc` and `$HOME/.screenrc`).

Answer (score 4):

Attach to the `screen` session. In another terminal, do the following:

```
screen -ls                           # to determine which screen session to access
screen -dr 1111.pts-1.foo -X 'help'  # substituting the screen session from the previous step
```

Now you should see a help screen in the attached `screen` session. At the top, the current command key will be listed next to "Command key:".